# Vim - change highlight of current quickfix line. (QuickFixLine)

Tags: vim, highlight

How to I change the highlighting of `QuickFixLine`, so that it has multiple highlights in one single line? For example:

Instead of highlighting the whole line like this:
[image: Quickfix window with currently highlighted line]

Change the foreground of the quickfix highlight to this:
[image: How I would like it to be]

How can I make this happen?

Comment: I guess by _green_ and _white_ you mean the same colors as the non-current lines, right?

Comment: It was just an example, I meant by that any kind of highlighting.

Comment: You can't. It's a single highlight group. You can only make it, for example, bold or reverse, and then other highlight groups (qfFileName or qfLineNr) will keep their colors.

Comment: What's does `:hi QuickFixLine` tell you right now? (You can use `:put =execute('hi QuickFixLine')` to paste that into a Vim buffer, which should make it easier to copy and paste here.)

Comment: And what's the colorscheme that you're using?

Comment: @filbranden, "onedark" (heavily customized by me). Here is the output: `QuickFixLine   xxx ctermfg=235 ctermbg=180 guibg=#334659` (by the way, it is not the style that you can see in the picture). But the subject is closed already, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really create multiple highlightings on the same line with `QuickFixLine`, in the general case.

However, `QuickFixLine` is applied *on top* of the highlighting that already exists in the quickfix window (which is defined by syntax rules.)

So, as long as you're not touching the particular attributes assigned by syntax rules (in this case, the foreground color) and you're only touching the other attributes (in this case, background color and setting text bold), you can achieve exactly the effect you're after.

For instance, applying this command should achieve the effect you're after:

```
:hi QuickFixLine ctermfg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=NONE gui=bold
```

You can make that permanent by adding a rule to your vimrc to apply that change after a colorscheme change, with:

```
augroup vimrc_colors
  au!
  au ColorScheme * hi QuickFixLine ctermfg=NONE cterm=bold guifg=NONE gui=bold
augroup END
```

It seems you're using a custom theme already, so you might want to consider modifying it to not set a foreground color and to set a bold attribute instead:

```
hi QuickFixLine
   \ ctermbg=180 cterm=bold
   \ guibg=#334659 gui=bold
```